# Script/Command (command line based or PowerShell) to delete an entire line containing a particular string value

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I am looking for a command or any script which I can use on Windows OS to delete an entire line from *.txt or *.csv files.

Case: I have a file named `abc.csv` having below mentioned lines. I would like to delete all the lines containing either `.dll`  or `volume`.

**abc.csv**

```
value.dll
setup.exe
installer.exe
setup.dll
volume serial
serial
```

After executing the script / command I would like to have `abc.csv` left with only below lines

Output file (**abc.csv**)

```
setup.exe
installer.exe
serial
```

Kindly suggest how can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch file solution:

```
@echo off
if not exist "abc.csv" goto :EOF
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /V /C:".dll" /C:"volume" "abc.csv" >"%TEMP%\abc.csv"
move /Y "%TEMP%\abc.csv" "abc.csv"
```

The line with **findstr** searches because of `/I` case-insensitive (Ignore case) for `.dll` or `volume` in file `abc.csv` and outputs because of `/V` (inVerted) all lines NOT containing one of those 2 strings.

Perhaps better for third line:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /V /C:"\.dll$" /C:"^volume" "abc.csv" >"%TEMP%\abc.csv"
```

Now with using regular expression `.dll` must be found at end of a line and `volume` must be found at beginning of a line to ignore that line on output.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Mofi for the details explaining. Your reply has answered and resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here a one line script to be run from the command-line with Ruby

```
ruby -ne 'print unless $_[/unwanted/]' < file.txt
```